# Is there a easier way to make document.getElementById simplified?

Tags: javascript

I am using code that requires me to write the following:

```
document.getElementById("id").innerHTML //+ whatever else
```

This code is getting used probably 20-30 times in my javascript with only the ID attribute changing. Is there a way I could write a very small function that replace this entire line of text with a more simplified version? Something like:

```
 El("id")
```

I have written probably 2-3 different functions to attempt to simply this, but none of them have worked.

```
var dom = {
    elem = function (id){
        return document.getElementById(id).innerHTML;
    }
}

dom.elem(testid) //this has not worked
```

Comment: The dom object has improper syntax. The elem key should be followed with a colon, not an equals sign.

Comment: Dare I suggest jQuery..?

Comment: What is the point of your wrapper? Thinking about it, it is completely redundant.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
function El(id) {
    return document.getElementById(id).innerHTML;
}
```

Then you can use:

```
El("elementId"); //will return document.getElementById("elementId").innerHTML
```

Comment: I tried this code, but it just tells me the ID attribute I put in, is not defined. I think the reason why is because the ID attribute must be a string, and the value i am inputing is not a string. If I manually make it a string, I get a error message back saying the entire thing is Null.

Comment: What are you inputting? (what data type, and value?)

Comment: I am putting in (health) rather than("health"). If I put in the first one, it says it is not defined. If I put in the 2nd one, it says the entire document.getElementById is Null.

Comment: Okay, so what is *health*? Could you give a link to the website maybe?

Comment: I don't have a website to link to as this is being done offsite. But health is the Id name to a Div in the HTML document. So I am targeting that specific div to change and update.

Comment: ok but I don't understand that health isn't a string? what data type is it and what's the error message when you try to String() it?

Comment: @user2763154 Passing `health` to it instead of `"health"` or `'health'` isn't going to work, because JavaScript will treat it as a variable. You should be passing a string or a variable whose value is a string. You said putting in a string didn't work... are you sure you have an element that has `id="health"`?

Comment: I got it somewhat to work and I'll try to explain what I did. In the function, I took off .innerHTML and put it on the code I was calling. This works, but its still extra code I have to write to do the same thing. The string value "health" I was putting in was valid, but returning the .innerHTML inside the function script is messing it up.

Answer (score 2):

You would rather want to return just an object to make the statement "document.getElementById" shorter.
Then you could use "obj(id)" and use it everywhere not only for the innerHTML method:

```
function obj(id){
    return document.getElementById(id);
}
```

use then for any JavaScript methods like:

```
obj("myElementId").innerHTML = "My new Text";
obj("myElementId").classList.add("mystyle");
obj("myElementId").click();
obj("myElementId").insertBefore();
```

where:

```
<div id="myElementId"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

another way...

```
  function get(value){ 
        return  document.querySelector(value).innerHTML
  }
```

then, use like this

```
get("#yourId")
```